# Set user after wp_create_user?

Tags: users

I have a form that creates a new user by using:

```
wp_create_user()
```

This works, but after this I want to auto log in the user.

I tried using:

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = 'username';
$creds['user_password'] = 'password';
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
       $msg =  $user->get_error_message();
       die($msg);
    } else {
        $output_form = true;
    }
```

But this creates a "headers already sent" error message because it's not at the top of the page.

Is there a way to auto log in the user after I have created the user?

Comment: Works if I add this right after the creation: wp_set_current_user($user_id);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function I wrote that hooks into the gravity forms create user form but it can be added to whatever action hook your wp_create_user function is attached to.

```
function my_auto_login( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
    wp_redirect( admin_url( 'profile.php' ) );
    exit;
}
```

The important part is `wp_set_auth_cookie`.  This has to fire after the user is the best (only?) way to auto login a user without filling out the login form.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the action hook `init` to catch and process the registration form.  This hook is called before anything is sent to the browser. If the form validates...

- Create the user with `wp_create_user`
- Log in the user with `wp_signon`
- Redirect the user using `wp_redirect` to the page of your choice

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned in my question I am getting a error message with wp_signon if I don't put it at the beginning of the page...trying to stay on the same page if possible.

Comment: The point is that you have do `wp_signon` before output, since that function sets headers.  You have to deal with the form submission before WP starts rendering the page.